# Getting Apache::ASP to run in OSX Lion Server - Updated for Mountain Lion

Tags: perl, apache, asp-classic, osx-lion

I am trying to get Apache::ASP running on OSX Lion Server.  I have made a fresh install of OSX Lion VM in Fusion 4, installed the Xcode app (with command line tools), and run the following shell commands:

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell

cpan> install CPAN

cpan> install Bundle::Apache::ASP
```

I've add to end of the httpd.confg files (/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf *and*
/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf.default):

```
 <Files ~ (\.asp)>    
    SetHandler  perl-script
    PerlHandler Apache::ASP
    PerlSetVar  Global .
    PerlSetVar  StateDir /tmp/asp
 </Files>
```

But either adding the set handler or perlhandler causes Apache not to restart.  Take them both out and Apache starts, but serves an .asp file as a text file....

UPDATE #1:

Oops, twenty or thirty:

```
 sudo apachectl restart
```

and I didn't even have mod perl running. Adding the below to the httpd.conf file got Apache to start:

```
LoadModule perl_module libexec/apache2/mod_perl.so
Alias /perl/ /Library/WebServer/Documents/perl/
<Location /perl/>
  SetHandler perl-script
  PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::Registry 
  PerlOptions +ParseHeaders
  Options +ExecCGI
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Location>
```

$Request->{Method} will now return a value, but....

```
   %test = $Request->ServerVariables(); #or $Request->ServerVariables(URL);
   %><%= $test %><%
```

Outputs:  Apache::ASP::Collection=HASH(0x7f84114c58d8)

UPDATE #2:

Several of the ServerVariables are undefined on Apache::ASP vs. IIS.  The syntax is slightly different than expected.  Below will list all available server variables...

```
my $variables = $Request->{ServerVariables};
print join '<br>', sort keys %$variables;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution has been added to question, but the short answer is that mod perl must be running (and does not start by default on OS X Lion...